# Firebase CI token is refreshed after few hours (locally or via github action)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, github-actions, firebase-tools

I have a deployment via github action manually as follows:

```
- npm i 
- npm build
- npm run deploy:ci -> firebase deploy -P $PROJECT_ID --only functions,hosting,firestore --force --token $FIREBASE_TOKEN --non-interactive`
```

FIRBASE_TOKEN is a token that i generated via  firebase login:ci
i got the token and saved in github action

from this week  after around 12h the token is refreshed or failed and i got message that i could not select this project or does not have permission

as i now the token should be long lived like it was until yesterday

how can i fix it?

if i will use GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS , i can save only the json in the secret , i cant provicde path to file
how could be fixed?

using google auth login from gcp will help ? firebase will be manage to detect it?